# Running a Bare Metal Assembly OS on AWS without Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, assembly, bare-metal

Wondering if it is possible to run an AWS instance that doesn't have Linux or any other operating system installed. Then which you could then install your own operating system such as [BareMetalOS](https://github.com/ReturnInfinity/BareMetal-OS).

Comment: I'm assuming you're referring to an EC2 environment other than the [i3.metal](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/announcing-general-availability-of-amazon-ec2-bare-metal-instances/) monster machines that start at ~$3500/month and give you direct hardware access.

Comment: $3500/month, wow. Yes anything where one could run their own OS.

Comment: Mind you, they do have 72 hyperthreaded 2.3GHz Xeon cores on 36 physical cores, 512 GiB of RAM and 8 x 1.9 TiB NVMe SSD drives, so it's a reasonable price in that light :) but afaik anything else is going to be either a Xen or KVM-ish virtual machine that expects a Linux or Windows guest.  Not sure whether this question might be better on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com) instead of SO since it isn't exactly a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: baremetal means no operating system.  assembly language is only a tiny part of it, barely required, generally another language is used like C.  Sounds like you are a long long way from being ready for using someone elses machine in a server farm, just start with your own computer(s).

Comment: The discussion here seems confused. The question is about running BareMetalOS directly on an EC2 instance, rather than running a mainstream heavyweight OS like Linux or Windows. Various non-mainstream OSs, such as NetBSD, can be baked into an AMI and run directly on an EC2 instance. EC2's expensive 'bare metal' instances are not relevant here.